# Publishing asp.net mvc application Connection String

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework in my Application.

I am publishing application for first time to somee.com
But I have the problem with the connection string.

My connection string in web.config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StoreDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.StoreModel.csdl|res://*/Models.StoreModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.StoreModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\StoreDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="StoreDB" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.StoreModel.csdl|res://*/Models.StoreModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.StoreModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\StoreDB.mdf;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and by database connection string on somee database is :

```
workstation id=storebd.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=****;pwd=****;data source=storebd.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=storebd
```

How should I format connection string in web.config file according to database connection provided by some.

Comment: try this : data source=storebd.mssql.somee.com;user id=****;pwd=****;persist security info=False;initial catalog=storebd

Comment: it is giving following error now

Comment: NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON

Comment: Replace the provider connection string part of the connection strings with this. If this does not work, you may have to contact hosting support. provider connection string=&quot;workstation id=storebd.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=****;pwd=****;data source=storebd.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=storebd&quot;"

Comment: i tried i was not working

Comment: you will have to contact hosting support

Comment: i have find the solution, thanks anyway

Comment: @Zeeshanhack You should have to post your solution in the answer. So, others can get help...